# Continuous function and intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I am struggling with the following questions:

> Let $g(x)$ be continuous in $[a,b]$ and $ 0 \leq r  \leq  1$
> I need to prove that there is $x_0 \in [a,b]$ that for him exists: $g(x_0)=rg(a)+(1-r)g(b)$

I know that for $r=0$ and $r=1$. I am getting immediate proof of that(it is the easy part). Where I am struggling is finding and understanding the values of $r$ I need to use.
I've tried defining a helping function $g(x)=rg(a)+(1-r)g(b)-g(x_0)$ but no success on that end.
I need to show that for $2$ different values in the range of $ 0 \lt r \lt 1$ one time I am getting a positive result and for the other a negative.

I am not asking for the solution, asking for guidance on how it can be done.

Thanks to everyone who will write an answer, much appreciated.

Comment: Assume g(a) = min(g(a), g(b). Then using IVT, if there is a $u$ such that $g(a) < u < g(b)$, then there exists $c$ such that $g(c) = u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(r)=rg(a)+(1-r)g(b).$  Note that for $r \in [0, 1], f(r)$ is necessarily between $g(a)$ and $g(b)$.  Then because $f(r)$ is between $g(a)$ and $g(b)$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to $g$, we know that for some $x_0 \in [a, b], g(x_0)=f(r)=rg(a)+(1-r)g(b)$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

**Key Realization:** In general for any interval $[x,y]$, any point $z \in [x,y]$ can be expressed by $$z = (1-\lambda)x + \lambda y$$ for some $\lambda \in [0,1]$. (Think of $\lambda$ as measuring a percentage distance traveled from $x$ to $y$.)

**Sketch:**

- With the above, what can you conclude about where $rg(a)+(1-r)g(b)$ lives, regardless of the value of $r \in [0,1]$?
- Since $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, alongside the realization from the previous line, the intermediate value theorem applies and therefore what follows?